# Multiple draws from multivariate normal distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let

```
  MU=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
  SIGMA=[2 0; 0 2]
```

I want to write some lines of code in Matlab to draw `R=10` unobservables from `Normal((MU(1,:),SIGMA), Normal((MU(2,:),SIGMA), Normal((MU(3,:),SIGMA)` without looping and store the results in a matrix 
`3x(R*2)`.

Comment: ...and what did you try, and where are you having problems?

Comment: I know I could do r1 = mvnrnd(MU(1,:),SIGMA,10);
r2 = mvnrnd(MU(2,:),SIGMA,10);
r3 = mvnrnd(MU(3,:),SIGMA,10) plus a loop to link them. I was wondering whether there is another way to do it without looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly from the sigma, you can see it is independent normal variables. So you don't need to use mvnrnd function. Just use randn which creates variables with zero mean and standard deviation of 1.

```
numSamples = 10;
mu = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
sigma = 2;
samples = sigma.*randn(numSamples, 6);
samples = bsxfun(@plus,samples,mu);
```

Used this because you said no looping.

Comment: Suggest you change your `mu` to a single vector: `mu = [1 2 3 4 5 6];`, then you do this for your last statement: `samples = bsxfun(@plus, samples, mu);`.  This basically achieves the same thing that you're doing, but has less typing.  Totally up to you, but I think `bsxfun` is cleaner here.